# JQuery form submission generates a new form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, user-input

I have a JQuery script that submits user input to a PHP script in the same file, and then displays the result of what the PHP script does with the input. That part works fine. The issue that I’m having is that, upon submission, the JQuery script (at least, I think it's the script) also generates a new submission box below the original.

I’m not sure why. I thought at first that it was an issue with the input type, with the asynchronous part, or even with where I had the form in the overall code, but none of those seem to be playing any role. I'm still a beginner and I'm just not seeing the issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "my_form">
verb <input type = "text" id ="word1"/>
<input type = "submit"/></form>
<div id="name"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_form").on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var verb = $ ("#word1").val();
    var tag = "#Latin ";
    var url = "http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/"+verb+tag;
        $.ajax({
            url: "Parser.php",
            data: {"verb": verb},
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            success: function(result){
                       $("#name").html(result);
                       $("#name").append(url);

                    }
        });
 });
});</script>
```

RESULT: 
[image: result of php script]

PHP

```
<?php 

    $bank = array();
    function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
        return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
    }
    function check_end_array($str, $ends)
    {
       foreach ($ends as $try) {
         if (substr($str, -1*strlen($try))===$try) return $try;
       }
       return false;
    }
    function db_connect() {

        static $connection;

        if(!isset($connection)) {
            $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','username','password','Verb_Bank');
        }

        if($connection === false) {
            return mysqli_connect_error(); 
        }
        return $connection;
    }
    function db_query($query) {
        $connection = db_connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        return $result;
    } 

    function db_quote($value) {
            $connection = db_connect();
            return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value) . "'";
        }
    $y = false;
    if (isset($_POST['verb'])){
    $y=db_quote($_POST['verb']);
    echo $y;
    echo "\n";

    $m = db_query("SELECT `conjugation` FROM normal_verbs WHERE (" . $y . ")  LIKE CONCAT('%',root,'%')");
    if($m !== false) {
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            }
    }
    foreach ($rows as $key => $value){
        if (in_array("first",$value)==true){
        echo "first conjugation verb\n";}
        $y = $_POST["verb"];
        $x = $y;
        foreach ($bank as $key => $value) 
           (series of IF-statements) 
    }}?>
```

Comment: Please show `Parser.php` code, or at least its currently returned `result`.

Comment: `$("#name").html(result);` inserts whatever HTML was returned from the server, If that HTML includes the original form over again, then that's what will be inserted.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Makes sense. So how do I change it so that the form is not included in returned HTML?

Comment: In other words, the problem lies server-side. The PHP script needs to be written such that it initially serves the whole page, including the form, then when called via AJAX, returns only what the AJAX expects.

Comment: Multi-purpose PHP scripts are generally written with a `switch-case` structure to control what content is delivered.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm somewhat confused. The PHP is just taking the input, comparing it to something in a database, and then echoing something back based on a combination of the database comparison and the input itself. Does that still mean that the problem is in the PHP? It doesn't even seem like it would be dealing with the form at all.

Comment: You said "... submits user input to a PHP script in the **same** file ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roamer-1888 says's the problem lies in server side, you are returning a html which has a input too. You need to change your code to return only the result string which you append to the div. Else if this is not possible doing at server side as it might require you to change lot of code, then you can strip off the input element from the result and then append it to the div. Like below.

```
 success: function(result){
                   var div = document.createElement('div');
                   div.innerHTML = result;
                   $(div).find('input').remove();

                   $("#name").html(div.innerHTML);
                   $("#name").append(url);

                }
```